# How do I create a python script that sorts document after amount of characters?

Tags: python

I have tried to create a script that counts a number of characters in all the files in a folder, and move the files with less than 50 characters to another folder.

```
import os

newPath = "E:\\Sorteret 3"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for fileName in files:
       if(fileName == 'sort.py'): continue
          words=line.split()
            if len(words) < 50 in open(os.path.join(root, fileName), 'r', encoding="Latin-1").read():
               os.rename(os.path.join(root, fileName), os.path.join(newPath, fileName))`
```

I get the following error:

`"Name line is not defined".`

Comment: Where are you reading a line of the file into 'line'?

Comment: I thought "line" was a built in function for a line in the document, but I'm not sure how to do it now.

Comment: I would do: Right after you find a file, open it and read all contents into file_contents or similar. Then do if len(file_contents) < 50: os.rename()... etc. I'll post some code in a response

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading anything into line.
I would read all the contents of the file and then do all checks:

```
import os
newPath = "<your path>"
oldPath = "<your path>"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(oldPath):
    for fileName in files:
        if(fileName == 'sort.py'): 
            continue
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fileName)
        len = os.stat(fpath).st_size

        if len < 50:
            os.rename(fpath, os.path.join(newPath, fileName))
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thanks mate. I did help with the files that has one line, but what about multiple lines?

Comment: The code above is not limited to files with one line. Are you sure it's not working on files with multiple line?

Comment: It does work on first try, but if I want to rescan the folder it wont run. I created a file with 3 lines of random numbers and character (Less than 50) and it did not move it the second time I create it.

Comment: Wouldn't `len = os.stat(fpath).st_size` be more efficient than reading each file to get the length?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It did not work. I'm not sure if its even scanning. (Note: It did work the first time). When I run the command in cmd python sort.py nothing happens.

Comment: If you can share your script and the files you are using I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the script you provided, and I have changed the paths.

Comment: Ok, but can you share the example files you are testing with?

Comment: Sure. I have uploaded the file to "Uploadfiles.io".

https://ufile.io/c7yh8

Comment: It works perfectly fine here every time I try with your file aaa.txt. I have no idea why it's not working on your end, this is extremely basic. I edited the code above to the exact one I'm currently using. Can you compare to yours real quick?